# Error H12 (Request timeout) on script but not on browser

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, heroku, libcurl

I have an php script that calls a ruby on rails web server. this web server is intended to be a api server on witch i will make several calls from the php script.

i have created a test route `/api/test` to see if my script can successfully call my api server.

on development everything works fine and no problems where found. but today, when i uploaded it to heroku i`m getting `Error H12 (Request timeout)`

so i open the same url on my browser. in the browser i cant see any error and the page is loaded the way it should.

my php script is something like this:

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $http_method); // GET, POST, PUT and DELETE, one at the time
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $response;
```

and this is the errors log, by the way, sometimes the GET request doesn't even show up as an error or success:

```
2012-08-23T13:28:07+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> POST *.herokuapp.com/api/test dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2012-08-23T13:28:08+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> PUT *.herokuapp.com/api/test dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2012-08-23T13:28:09+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> DELETE *.herokuapp.com/api/test dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

sometimes one of the 4 requests returns something, but is like accidentally

can someone help me? i really need this script working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

It was the firewall on my company.

Dont know where, but once my machine was clear of the restrictions it is working now